# Converting all files (.jpg to .png) from a directory in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert all files from a directory from .jpg to .png. The name should remain the same, just the format would change.

I've been doing some researches and came to this:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

directory = r'D:\PATH'

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        im = Image.open(filename)
        im.save('img11.png')
        print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

I was expecting the loop to go through all my .jpg files and convert them to .png files. So far I was doing only with 1 name: 'img11.png', I haven't succed to build something able to write the adequate names.

The `print(os.path.join(directory, filename))` works, it prints all my files but concerning the converting part, it only works for 1 file.

Do you guys have any idea for helping me going through the process?

Comment: For you change extension from .jpg to .png is a good convertion?

Comment: Pleas read this: https://www.quora.com/What-happens-when-you-rename-a-jpg-to-a-png-file

Comment: But he doesnt renames files @Wonka Image package will convert to another format. So not sure who gave that `-1`

Comment: @Wonka This is for a ML project, I need to train an algorithm on .jpg / .png / .pdf files. As I have a massive quantity of .jpg, I need to split my dataset in order to have a equally distributed dataset

Comment: I'm not a python expert but since you save every file with the same name wouldn't it go through all the files and overwrite it every time. try saving with an index at the end that itsrates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert the opened image as RGB and then you can save it in any format. 
You can try the following code :

```
from PIL import Image
import os

directory = r'D:\PATH'
c=1
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
        im = Image.open(filename)
        name='img'+str(c)+'.png'
        rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
        rgb_im.save(name)
        c+=1
        print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 2):

You're explicitly saving every file as `img11.png`.
You should get the name of your `jpg` file and then use that to name and save the `png` file.

```
name = filename[:-4]
im.save(name + '.png')
```

Comment: It works perfectly, both for converting into .png & .pdf. Thanks @Arienrhod

Comment: Works, but not a good solution in the long run. Here we are assuming that the *extension* of the file would only be of 3 characters (in length), which may not be true (***ex. `.jpeg`, `.tiff`*** etc). So rather i would suggest you to use something like `os.path.splittext()[0]` in order to get the true filename regardless of the length of the extension.

Comment: or last split with '.' [1] can also work

Answer (score 2):

I would have used os.rename() function like below.

```py
import os 
directory = r'D:\PATH' 
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    prefix = filename.split(".jpg")[0]
    os.rename(filename, prefix+".png")
```

Please let me know if this is what you wanted. Try the code with some copied images inside a test folder, before applying to the intended folder. All the best.

Comment: Thanks @Amit it works ton convert into .png files. But it strangely, doesn't to convert to .pdf files. It says that the type of file is unsupported or damaged. Do you know why ?

Comment: Apologies. I somehow read your request as to rename and not convert. I was doing two things at a time. Sincere apologies. My previous code will only rename. Usability is most likely destroyed as only extension was changed. I will post another answer now. It will be basically a very small edit in your program. Sorry again.

Comment: @Grégoire de Kermel. Since you have accepted my solution, I will request you to see my last post (at the bottom of the page). If you can not unselect my answer and select a better answer in this page, please let me know (if the answer at the bottom of the page works). If it does, I will swap both answers. Otherwise in future somebody seeing this post (and if in a hurry) might use a wrong solution and suffer. Please help me correct the post, else kindly choose some other answer as solution. The idea is not to look smart but prevent misdirection, in future, to somebody. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```py
from PIL import Image 
import os 
directory = r'D:\PATH' 
for filename in os.listdir(directory): 
    if filename.endswith(".jpg"): 
        prefix = filename.split(".jpg")[0]
        im = Image.open(filename)
        im.save(prefix+'.png')  
    else: 
        continue
```

Please try this one and let me know.

Comment: it should be like that 
from PIL import Image 
import os  in next line 
directory = r'D:\PATH' // next line